# How to mask textfield value in ext.net

Tags: textfield, mask, ext.net

I have textfield and i want to mask like that `999.99.99.99.99` I try this

```
<ext:TextField ID="txtNumber" runat="server" AllowBlank="false" 
                                            >
                                            <Plugins>
                                                <ext:InputMask ID="InputMask1" runat="server" Mask="999.99.99.99.99.99" ClearWhenInvalid="False" />
                                            </Plugins>
                                        </ext:TextField>
```

also the user can enter 999.99 or 999 or 999.99.99 kind of value in this textfield. How can i manage it.
Thank you

Comment: Your code looks correct. Does this sample help solve the problem? http://examples.ext.net/#/Form/TextField/InputMask/

Answer (score 0):

U can try **regex** instead of mask. ext:TextField has the Regex property.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a MaskSymbol as the third field in this example: [Form > TextField > InputMask](http://examples4.ext.net/#/Form/TextField/InputMask/).

And use a regex like @CocLn suggested. Maybe something like this:

```
<ext:TextField ID="txtNumber" runat="server" AllowBlank="false">
    <Plugins>
        <ext:InputMask
            ID="InputMask1"
            runat="server"
            Mask="999~"
            ClearWhenInvalid="False">
            <MaskSymbols>
                <ext:MaskSymbol Name="~" Regex="(\.[0-9]{2}){0,4}" />
            </MaskSymbols>
        </ext:InputMask>
    </Plugins>
</ext:TextField>
```

This should require 3 digits and a sequence 0 to 4 times of a dot followed by two digits. If the first digit after each dot is optional (e.g. 999.9.99 is valid), then just turn the `{2}` bit into `{1,2}`.